# Adicionar elemento ao início de um objeto chave/valor

Tags: javascript, objetos

Possuo o seguinte objeto:

```
var exemploLista = {
    "Igor": "exemplo1.jpg",
    "Joao": "exemplo2.jpg"
};
```

E estou utilizando esse código para adicionar um item ao objeto:

```
exemploLista["Lucas"] = "exemplo3.jpg";
```

Mas, dessa maneira, ao dar `console.log(exemploLista)` é retornado:

> Object {Igor: "exemplo1.jpg", Joao: "exemplo2.jpg", Lucas: "exemplo3.jpg"}

E eu gostaria de o elemento adicionado não ficasse no fim da `array` e sim no início, e, também, se o elemento já existir na `array` ele sair da sua "posição" e ir para o início.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `exemploLista` que você está usando e é criado com a notação `{...}` é um [objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) e não um [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Em javascript objetos são basicamente [hash maps](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o) ({chave: valor}) e segundo a especificação que define a sintaxe/regras da linguagem um objeto é "uma coleção não ordenada de propriedades com valores".

Então da maneira como você construiu seu objeto `exemploLista` não há como deixar ele em qualquer ordem desejada, você deve considerar que os valores vão sair sempre em ordem aleatória, o fato de você ter testado e os valores terem sido impressos na ordem em que você colocou eles no objeto (`Object {Igor: "exemplo1.jpg", Joao: "exemplo2.jpg", Lucas: "exemplo3.jpg"}`) pode ser considerado puro acaso e pode (leia-se vai) variar conforme o browser a até mesmo conforme a versão do mesmo.

Se você quer garantir a ordem uma boa opção é utilizar [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) verdadeiros, um esboço de como você poderia fazer o que quer:

```
var exemploLista = [];
exemploLista[1] = {nome: "Igor", imagem: "exemplo1.jpg"};
exemploLista[2] = {nome: "Joao", imagem: "exemplo2.jpg"};

exemploLista[0] = {nome: "Lucas", imagem: "exemplo3.jpg"};
```

No código acima Lucas seria adicionado por último, mas ficaria na primeira posição do array. Para remover "Lucas" do array caso ele já existisse antes de ser adicionado você precisar iterar sobre o array exemploLista, checar em cada posição se existe um objeto com o nome Lucas, remover se existir e após o fim do laço adicionar lucas na posição desejada. Note que você também teria que rearranjar as posições do array para ele não fique como elementos vazios. Não vou adicionar mais código e explicações pois a resposta já está bem longa então sugiro que leia os links sobre objetos e arrays que passei para que entenda a diferença e depois poste uma nova questão mais específica se ainda precisar.

Answer (score 5):

Seu exemplo não é um array - na verdade você está utilizando propriedades indexadas de um *hashmap*.

Para que `exemploLista` seja tratado como um *array*, você deve popular a variável da seguinte maneira:

```
var exemploLista = [
    {nome: "Igor", imagem: "exemplo1.jpg"}, 
    {nome: "Joao", imagem: "exemplo2.jpg"}
];
```

Neste caso, para incluir um item na primeira posição utilize o método `array.unshift()`. De acordo com a documentação da Mozilla,

> O método unshift() adiciona um ou mais elementos no início de um array e retorna o número de elementos (propriedade length) atualizado.

Seu uso, portanto, seria o seguinte:

```
exemploLista.unshift({nome: 'Lucas', imagem: 'exemplo3.jpg'});
```

Com o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note os valores do registro `[0]`.

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Answer (score 1):

você pode criar uma `Class` para encapsular a sua lista, então crie um método `set` no prototype desta `Class` que reordene as keys sempre que um novo elemento for inserido.

```js
var Lista = function (obj) {
  //inserindo elementos iniciais
  if (obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
}

Lista.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
  //reordenando os elementos, a nova tupla deve ficar no topo.
  var obj = {};
  for (var prop in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop != key) {
      obj[prop] = this[prop];
      delete this[prop];
    }
  }
  this[key] = value;
  for (var prop in obj) {
    this[prop] = obj[prop];
  }
}

Lista.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
  for (var key in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      callback(this[key], key);
    }
  }
}

var lista = new Lista({ "Igor": "exemplo1.jpg", "Joao": "exemplo2.jpg" });
lista.set("Lucas", "exemplo3.jpg");
lista.set("Joao", "exemplo4.jpg");
lista.forEach(function (value, key) {
  console.log(value, key);
});
```

Realizei uma pequena atualização no exemplo acima, implementando uma função forEach para a lista (que na verdade é um HashMap).

Comment: Embora seja uma ótima solução não acho uma boa ideia você usar o termo `Class` para se referir a função construtora `Lista`, afinal javascript não possui classes e isso provavelmente vai confundir o user que fez a pergunta (veja que ele já estava confundindo objetos com arrays) e outras pessoas.

Comment: Funcionou, porém como eu poderia tratar esses dados? Estou tentando assim: `listaExemplo = new Lista({"Igor": "exemplo1.jpg", "Joao": "exemplo2.jpg"});` porém ao usar `$.each(listaExemplo, function(index, value) {
                $("body").append(index+" - "+value);
            });` o seguinte é retornado: _Igor - exemplo1.jpgJoao - exemplo2.jpgset - function (a,t){var e={};for(var o in this)this.hasOwnProperty(o)&&o!=a&&(e[o]=this[o],delete this[o]);this[a]=t;for(var o in e)this[o]=e[o]}_

Comment: @BrunoRB, entendo que não é correto chamar este tipo de estrutura de classe, porém no ECMA5, este tipo de estrutura é aquilo que mais se aproxima de uma classe, tanto que neste Guia: [Introdução ao JavaScript Orientado a Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript), o autor o chama de `Classe`, talvez por acreditar que para fins didaticos é valido fazer esta corelação entre OO e Orientação a Prototipos.

Comment: @Igor, como apontado pelo Bruno, você não tem como garantir a ordem das propriedades de um objeto, por um outro lado, o objeto [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) garanti esta ordem, porém ele é suportado apenas pelas versões mais recentes dos Browsers, o que você pode fazer é usar a implementação acima para implementar o seu proprio `HashMap` com as caracteristicas e métodos necessarios.

Comment: @TobyMosque se eu implementar o exemplo que você postou, funcionará em todas as versões dos navegadores ou somente os mais recentes?

Comment: @TobyMosque outra dúvida. Se eu quisesse, ao invés de deixar o objeto no início, deixar ele no final, qual seria a adaptação no código? Obrigado!